# How to Activate Virtual Environment in Virtual Studio?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I am a newbie. I usually activate the virtual environment in Visual Studio using the following command:

```
$ & "c:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Python Yamed/venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1"
```

But iam not sure why I am getting this error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
```

Can someone give advice please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
$ source "c:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Python Yamed/venv/Scripts/Activate"
```